# What happened to the band in Daft Punk's 'One More Time'?

Tags: music

I remember a long time ago, listening to Daft Punk's *One More Time*. There was, in the music video, a band that gets kidnapped. Was this 'story' ever concluded? What happened to the band?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The band is captured and taken to earth as part of a dastardly plan by a shady figure known as 'Earl'. They later escape and return home.

The story was later expanded into a full, dialogue-less film called *Interstellar 5555* , with each song from Daft Punk's album *Discovery* covering a chapter. A detailed (spoiler-warning !) summary of the film is available on [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstella_5555%3a_The_5tory_of_the_5ecret_5tar_5ystem#section_1).

Comment: I ended up making a playlist of the story (and songs) of the various videos on YouTube as well. The link for it is [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE98AE9845B227891), though I can't remember if I saved them in the correct order.